# Share permissions when accessed locally via UNC

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, active-directory, unc, permissions

I have a w2k3 server (terminal server) and a domain user.

If the user accesses "`\\TS\Folder`" from another computer, that user can read\write without any problem. If I login to "TS" as the user, they cannot access the folder "`\\TS\Folder`" using the UNC convention. "C:\Folder" works fine. I even tried adding the user to the admin group of TS and it still did not allow access when using the UNC path locally.

I've relogged, rebooted, gpupdate'ed, etc. Any ideas? I cannot think of a reason why the user can access with the UNC path on other computers but not with the UNC path locally.

EDIT:
Situations tried:

BadUser on TS to \\TS\Folder = Fail

BadUser on TS to C:\Folder = Pass

BadUser on TS to \\xp1\Folder = Pass

BadUser on xp1 to \\TS\Folder = Pass

BadUser on xp1 to \\xp1\Folder = Pass

Comment: It it just that particular user or does this happen for any user in your domain?

Comment: Can the user access \\someotherserver\folder while logged on to TS?

Comment: @Zoredache - Just this user. Other users can access it fine

@nray - Yes, I can connect to other shares on other servers

Comment: Is 'TS' the actual computer name or an alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it turns out I left out an important detail: The folder contains vbs files, it worked when I tired to access a plain text doc or word doc. We also recently updated to ie7. I had to add "file://ts" to the trusted sites list in IE7. It works better now.

Thanks for your help. Hopefully, MS will remove IE dependence one day.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you checked the share permissions, but have you checked the folder permissions as well?

Comment: Yes, I checked both. I can access it from another computer, I cannot access it locally with the UNC path

Comment: I also added the user to the Local Admin group and it still did not work

Comment: Have you enabled file and print sharing on your firewall? It's possible that this traffic could be getting blocked.

Comment: firewall is disabled

Answer (score 0):

Anything in the event logs and can you connect to shares on other servers?

Check to see if the Workstation service is having issues.

Comment: Nothing from the Workstation service in the logs. I have connected to other shares in the network without issue.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with Windows XP SP1 that would cause this to happen - the problem was related to the loopback interface (127.0.0.1) being unable to tell the NetBIOS over TCP requestor the interface speed. This was fixed in one of the post SP1 hotfixes IIRC and I've never heard of it affecting Windows 2003 but they shared a lot of code so it's possible.

Are you seeing Event log entries with ID 3019 when the attempt to map to the UNC path fails?

Comment: I do have some 3019 events, although it does not always create an event when access is denied.